# Set Property value with Burn

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Untilmately I am having problems setting Property value that is result of other properties in Bundle package.
I tried using CustomAction but with no luck.
What is the right way to set property value in a bundle that is dependent on other properties?

My end goal is to detect presence of VC++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable.
The problem is that Version registry key for detecting it has a prefix "v" before the version number e.g. "v10.0.40219.325".

I did test it and found out the the following expression does not work correctly when prefix "v" exists:
            InstallCondition="NOT VC10_RUNTIME OR (VC10_RUNTIME < v10.0.40219.01)">

So what I thought is to extract from registry the values for MajorVersion, MinorVersion, Bld, Rbld and concatenate them into a new property. I will then use this new property that is without "v" prefix in the InstallCondition and DetectCondition.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With Wix 3.8.722 a new feature allows you to write a BAFunction.dll in C# and read properties in OnDetectComplete (or read the registry directly) and then set a property for the Condition.  You can also do this in Wix 3.7 if you use the WixBalExtensionExt.dll from wixextba.codeplex.com

Comment: My request is not really valid as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419006/registrysearch-vs-utilregistrysearch-in-burn).