# RegistrySearch vs util:RegistrySearch in Burn

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) to build a WiX bootstrapper. I realized that RegistrySearch as shown below does not actually search the registry. I used [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) to monitor registry access.

```
<Property Id="NETFX35VERSION" Secure="yes">
    <RegistrySearch Id="RegSearchNetFx35" Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5"
        Name="Version" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

However, when I used the `util` function it was working fine and the registry got queried fine:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" 
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" 
                     Value="Version" 
                     Variable="NETFX35VERSION" />
```

Is this expected behavior with the WiX Burn tool?

Answer (score 8):

`Property` and `RegistrySearch` are concepts for .msi packages. Bundles (bootstrappers) aren't processed by the MSI engine so they have other concepts, like [`Variable`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html) and [`util:RegistrySearch`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/registrysearch.html). They're similar and generally bundles have more functionality in searches than the MSI equivalent.

Comment: Is there any case where `Property` should be used in Burn at all? I am curious why it was not made unavailable to be used in Burn.

Comment: No, Property has no effect in a bundle and cannot be used as a child of the Bundle element: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html. It can be present in a Fragment that you reference from Bundle. Currently WiX doesn't show a warning or error when you do so. It's a reasonable feature request: http://wixtoolset.org/issues/

Comment: So you are saying that `DetectCondition` and `InstallCondition` of 'ExePackage' are using wix variables, not properties.
E.g. 

    `DetectCondition="NETFX35VERSION AND (NETFX35VERSION &gt;= v3.5.30729.1)"
    InstallCondition="NOT NETFX35VERSION OR (NETFX35VERSION &lt; v3.5.30729.1)">`

Comment: Sounds very reasonable and logical of course. Just I wish they were not set in all caps and confuse the average wix user.