# WiX Bootstrapper: use util:RegistrySearch result as path in util:FileSearch?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

can i use a util:RegistrySearch to retrieve a path from a registry key and use that path in a util:FileSearch to check if a file in that directory exists?

---

**Example**

i have a path to an executable stored in a registry key.

`HKLM\Software\MyApp\  ->  C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApplication.exe`

and i want to use as detect condition if a different file within this directory (e.g.: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\AnotherFile.dll ) exists.

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SearchForMyApp"
                     Variable="MyApp_Found"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp"
                     Result="exists"
                     Win64="no"
                     After="SearchForOtherFile"
                     />

<util:FileSearch Id="SearchForOtherFile"
                 Variable="OtherFile_Found"
                 Result="exists"
                 Path="AnotherFile.dll" Comment="<-- how to use path from reg search here"
                 />
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.

Use "After" attributes in order to define the one should come after.
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/registrysearch.html

Comment: but then i can only search for a file in a path i define, right? how can i use the path found by the registry search? (i've updated the question with an example)

Comment: Place the registry search inside property element and then use the property inside the file search. Check for example : http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html

Comment: first, the registry contains a path including a filename, does that still work?
second, i need it for the bootstrapper (util::RegistrySearch), not the msi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419006/registrysearch-vs-utilregistrysearch-in-burn

Comment: sorry my mistake i meant variable. Use http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/registrysearch.html and http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/filesearch.html. Perform registry search and palce it in a variable and then use that variable in the path attribute in filesearch, the result if exist or not will be place in the variable you define.