# [Wix][PostgreSQL] How to add an install condition in bundle

Tags: postgresql, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to add a condition before installing PostgreSQL on Wix bundle.
I'm expecting it to check if there is an installed version of PostgreSQL as you can see on my following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="Title" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Manufacture" UpgradeCode="5aee5af2-10c7-42d1-bde6-c7dadf736786">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>

    <?define InstallPgCommand=--unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --superpassword "super_pwd" --servicename "service_name" --servicepassword "service_pwd" --serverport 5433?>

    <Chain>
      <!-- Install postgres -->
      <ExePackage
        SourceFile="ThirdPartyApps\postgresql-14.3-1-windows-x64.exe"
        Compressed ="yes"
        Vital ="yes"
        Permanent ="yes"
        InstallCommand="$(var.InstallPgCommand)"
        InstallCondition="NOT POSTGRESINSTALLED"
        />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="POSTGRESINSTALLED">
      <RegistrySearch Id="POSTGRESINSTALLED_SEARCH" Key="SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Name="Branding" />
    </Property>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

But it didn't work as expect.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

`RegistrySearch` is for MSI packages. For bundles, use [`util:RegistrySearch`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/registrysearch.html) instead.

Comment: I added util but recognize it, and gave me the following error : `Namespace prefix 'util' is not defined.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419006/registrysearch-vs-utilregistrysearch-in-burn

Comment: I still don't get it, how can I use the prefix 'util' ?